# EC2 Create Image EBS volume seems to remain the same

Tags: amazon-ec2

Production went down today with no disk space remaining error.  After deleting files and restarting the machine, it still came up with this error, even if I just try to touch a new empty file.

It is probably caused by running out of inodes, but I went ahead and created an "Image" which seems to create an AMI, but after launching an instance of the AMI the same problem persisted... probably because it is using the same EBS volume.

Question is: how do I snapshot the EBS volume and then connect a new volume to the AMI as the root fs?

Comment: You should try find the real reason for no disk space error.

Answer (score 0):

You care correct that the "Create Image" command creates an Amazon Machine Image (AMI). If you start a new EC2 instance with this AMI, it will contain the same data as the machine that was imaged. That's why you are copying your exiting problem to the new instance.

Check your disk space with `df -h` to confirm that you have space available.

If you require more disk space, you can copy your disk to a larger volume as follows:

**Option 1:** If you already have an AMI of the volume:

- Launch a new instance using the AMI, but expand the size of the volume in the **Add Storage** options

**Option 2:** If you want to retain the same instance:

- **Stop** your instance
- **Create Snapshot** of the EBS Volume
- **Create Volume** from the Snapshot, specifying a larger storage size
- **Detach** the original root volume
- **Attach** the new volume in its place (keep the same Device identifier)

In both cases, after startup confirm that the partition has automatically expanded. If not, use the `resize2fs` command to extend the partition.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an image of an ec2 instance, it takes snapshots of the volumes also. You can see this in "Images > AMIs" and snapshots information is visible in "Block Devices" column (By default, this column is not visible) of the table.

Now, if you are getting the "no disk space error", you need to increase the size of root volume. You can do that by following the link below:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html